# Is it possible to define an acronym during the text?

Tags: acronyms, acro

So, noob here, I am learning to use the `acro` package to write reports. Such as:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{acro}  
\acsetup{first-style=short}
```

Then I use

```
\DeclareAcronym{ny}{short = NY ,  long  = New York ,  class = abbrev}
```

because I have noticed that it must be put before

```
\begin{document}.
```

Since I have several acronyms/nomenclature/simbols to write, it would be better to define them as they appear in my text, instead of using `\ac{NY}` on it, I believe.

It would be even better because it would be easier to find errors of misspelling or different writing in

```
\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]
```

at the end. Is there a solution for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question. You cannot use `\DeclareAcronym` in the document, it can (or rather should) only be used in the preamble. There is no guarantee whatsoever that things work if you use it after `\begin{document}`.

You also cannot use `\ac{foo}` in the document without declaring the acronym `foo` first in the preamble. BTW, using `\ac{foo}` is not *instead* of declaring it in the preamble but in *addition* to it.

You *can* however list declared but unused acronyms in the list of acronyms by “using” them with `\acuse` (see the manual for details).

So the answer is: no, you cannot declare acronyms on the fly with the `acro` package.